# SoftLayer API for Netscaler VPX 10.5

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I got error messages when I requested SoftLayer REST API for Netscaler VPX 10.5. Could I know if SoftLayer REST API supports Netscaler VPX 10.5? Here are some examples:

Request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller/20705/getLoadBalancers.json
```

Response:

```
{"error":"There was a problem processing the reply from the application tier. Please contact development.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

Another example

Request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller/20705/createLiveLoadBalancer.json
{"parameters":[{"loadBalancingMethod":"rr","name":"demo_vip1","sourcePort":80,"type":"HTTP","virtualIpAddress":"169.45.156.212"}]}
```

Response:

```
{"error":"There was a problem processing the reply from the application tier.  Please contact development.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **these methods are only supported for Netscaler VPX 10.1**. They are not supported for 10.5.

If you wish to create Load Balancer services, it's necessary to configure this manually in the Netscaler.